# Firebase database not working after a new app version is installed. Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase realtime database and firebase auth. My problem happens when an new app version is released. If the user is logged in and update app, it doesn't get data from firebase database. To read the data, i have to logout, reinstall app and then login again.
It happens on iOS, but i didn't test it on android yet.

edit: My app isn't launched yet. These tests were made using testflight.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add a splashscreen on your app that every time an user open it, the screen will check if that user is logged in. If not, you could ask for a new login, or save some encrypted data to automatically login.